# How can I get sound working in an Android app running on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: android, audio, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I'm writing an Android app to run on the [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html) platform, on a Raspberry Pi 3. So far I've got a simple app with one main activity running. I put a button in the layout and plugged in a mouse to the Pi so I could click the button. I'm trying to get the button's click handler to play an MP3 sound file; here's a snippet of the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_audio);
    }

    public void myButtonOnClick(View view) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I run this on an Android Emulator, it works fine. I hear the sound. But when I move this over onto my Raspberry Pi 3 running Android Things, it no longer plays any sound when I click the button. I have tried listening in on both the 3.5 mm audio jack and the HDMI port (that is, I have it plugged into a TV which can play audio from the HDMI input). Why isn't sound working?

Comment: [Sound not working on raspberry pi with Android Things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487650/sound-not-working-on-raspberry-pi-with-android-things)

Comment: And FYI: ultimately the reason I need sound working is actually to make use of Google's [Nearby API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/) - specifically utilizing the near-ultrasonic sound transmissions that it uses.

Comment: You should provide more info regarding the conditions you test the sound against. Because for the minimum code you've provided I can perfectly hear sound with Dev Preview 3. Are you sure `myButtonOnClick` is being invoked? :) Sometimes, defining `onClick` xml attribute, doesn't trigger the callback... Also, any relevant info in logcat?

Comment: Any logcat info from MediaPlayer?

Comment: have you tried getting the reference to the xml button and using `setOnClickListener` rather than using the XML attribute (which we are assuming you are doing since we can't see it in your example)

Comment: In addition to `onClick`-thing, just move `mediaPlayer.start()` below `MediaPlayer.create()`. If it plays the problem is the `onClick`, if not the problem is either your hardware or cables.